# Problems with postfix and sending mails

Tags: linux, email, centos, postfix

I have ran into problems while configuring my postfix for my CENTOS machine.

Note:The mailserver itself should be localhost only and only be able to send mail internally.

the following shows up when I use `tail -f /var/log/maillog`

```
Aug 24 22:51:54 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup pid 8135 exit status 1
Aug 24 22:51:54 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 24 22:52:14 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
Aug 24 22:52:54 localhost postfix/cleanup[8158]: fatal: open lock file pid/unix.cleanup: cannot open file: Permission denied
Aug 24 22:52:55 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup pid 8158 exit status 1
Aug 24 22:52:55 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 24 22:53:14 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
Aug 24 22:53:55 localhost postfix/cleanup[8182]: fatal: open lock file pid/unix.cleanup: cannot open file: Permission denied
Aug 24 22:53:56 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup pid 8182 exit status 1
Aug 24 22:53:56 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/cleanup: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 24 22:54:14 localhost postfix/master[7188]: warning: unix_trigger_event: read timeout for service public/pickup
```

This is my current configuration in the `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
   queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = localhost
mydomain = localdomain
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
default_transport = error:outside mail is not deliverable
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
mynetworks_style = host

debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

home_mailbox = Maildir/

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no

manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
```

I send mail though MIME:Lite module with the perl script that is listed below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Lite;


    my $message = MIME::Lite->new(
                    From            =>      'root@localhost.localdomain',
                    To              =>      'root@localhost.localdomain',
                    Subject         =>      'hello',
                    Type            =>      'Multipart/Mixed',
                    );
```

I have missed out on something. I havent configured much but I cant seem to find the source to why its not working. any help or tips would be greatly apreciated.